# Slim Framework accessing the flash message in twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, slim

I'm using Slim 3 and cannot access the flash message ([slim/flash](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash)) in my twig template. Here are my codes:

**Router:**

```
    $this->flash->addMessage('msg', 'Account with ID '.$id.' has been deleted.');
    return $res->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/dashboard/accounts');
```

**Template:**

```
{{ ["slimFlash"]["msg"][0] }}
```

I'm not getting any error though I tried to `print_r($_SESSION)` and this is what I got:

```
[slimFlash] => Array
    (
        [msg] => Array
            (
                [0] => Account with ID 1 has been deleted.
            )

    )
```

That's why I tried {{ ["slimFlash"]["msg"][0] }} but it still didn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding a middleware

```
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $this->view->offsetSet("flash", $this->flash->getMessages());
    $response = $next($request, $response);

    return $response;
});
```

and then in my template

```
{{ flash["msg"][0] }}
```